# Branch not measuring correctly install events from Google Ads App Install campaigns

Tags: branch.io

I'm having trouble measuring the correct number of installs in Branch.io from an app campaign I've created in Google Ads. I already have the integration between both platforms and I know it is working due to the correct number of clicks.

Is there any way to correct that any of you are aware of?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?